# How to find which string occuring first in text among multiple strings?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, smarty, preg-split

I have text like this, "wow! It's Amazing.". I need to split this text by either "!" or "." operator and need to show the first element of array(example $text[0]).

```
$str="wow! it's, a nice product.";
$text= preg_split('/[!.]+/', $str);
```

here $text[0] having the value of "wow" only. but I want to know which string occurring first in text (whether its "!" or "."), so that I will append it to $text[0] and shown like this "wow!".

I want to use this preg_split in smarty templates.

```
<p>{assign var="desc" value='/[!.]+/'|preg_split:'wow! it's, a nice product.'}
{$desc[0]}.</p>
```

the above code displays the result as "wow". There is no preg_match in smarty, so far i have searched.other wise,i would use that.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `preg_split` you should use `preg_match`:

```
$str="wow! it's, a nice product.";
if ( preg_match('/^[^!.]+[!.]/', $str, $m) )
   $s = $m[0]; //=> wow!
```

If you must use `preg_split` only then you can do:

```
$arr = preg_split('/([^!.]+[!.])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
   $s = $arr[0]; //=> wow!
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. But i want to implement in smarty files like this "<p> {assign var="desc" value='/[!.]+/'|preg_split:$product.description_short}
 {$desc[0]}.</p>"

Comment: See my update if that helps. Otherwise please post the code in question as it is difficult to read it from comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 /(.+[!.])(.+)/
```

it will split the string in to two.

$1 => wow!

$2 => it's, a nice product.

[see here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3RH)

Comment: `(whether its "!" or ".")` but you only check for `!`